# Wordpress - Display specific Meta Name and Value

Tags: wordpress, metadata

I can't find a specific answer that has been helpful.
I have woocommerce products with 28 additional meta fields. Some that are simple text and some that are URLs.
I am trying to figure out how to display the Meta Key Name as well as the value individually rather than as a loop. This is so I can add appropriate HTML and CSS around each item as needed.

Example:
Meta Key Name : Meta Value

Batteries Included : No

Full Engineering Drawing : https://www.websiteaddress.com/drawings/1024-4.5.pdf

Comment: Where do you want to show them? On the single product page? How did you add the meta? Using a plugin or your own code? The link is not working, just endless loading.

Comment: It was an example URL...that's why it isn't working.
Yes, on a single product page. Using PHP in the single product page template.
If you are in the product and you select Screen Options you can see "Custom Fields" as an option. When you select this you can add all of the custom fields you want. But to get them to display is my big question.
I just don't know the PHP syntax to call out a specific field. I don't want to loop through.

Comment: Hahaha God I'm stupid, That was the example of the meta xD. You can probably just echo the specific field. I'll try to write you an example in a little bit.

Comment: I feel asleep putting my daughter to bed, sorry!
I've written an answer for your question.
Since you don't want to loop trough I think this is the way you're going to have to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you do not want to loop trough the meta I think your best bet is doing it like this:

I use the if statements to only echo the field if the meta is added to that product.

```
    //Add all meta keys here individually
    $batteries  = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), "Batteries Included", true );
    $drawing    = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), "Full Engineering Drawing", true );
    //Check if meta value is empty and only display if not
    if(!($batteries == null || $batteries == '')) {
        echo '<div class="battery-div">' . '<span class="batteries">Batteries Included: </span>' . '<span class="battery-value">' . $batteries . '</span>' . '</div>';
    }
    if(!($drawing == null || $drawing == '')) {
        echo '<div class="drawing-div">' . '<span class="engineering_drawing">Full Engineering Drawing: </span>' . '<span class="drawing-value">' . $drawing . '</span>' . '</div>';
    }
```

But if you loop trough the meta you could do something like this instead:

```
//Get product meta
$meta_info = get_post_meta(get_the_ID());
//Loop trough meta
foreach($meta_info as $key=>$val){
    //If meta key is this and not empty echo this
    if ($key == 'Batteries Included' && !($val == null || $val == '')) {
        echo '<div class="battery-div">' . '<span class="battery-name">' . $key . ' : ' . '</span>' . '<span class="battery-value">' . $val[0] . '</span>' . '</div>';
    }
    if ($key == 'Full Engineering Drawing' && !($val == null || $val == '')) {
        echo '<div class="drawing-div">' . '<span class="drawing-name">' . $key . ' : ' . '</span>' . '<span class="drawing-value">' . $val[0] . '</span>' . '</div>';
    }
}
```